# Do internal artifacts belong in a repository?

Tags: build, build-process, repository, libraries, ivy

Our team is struggling with issues around the idea of a library repository. I have used Maven, and I am familiar with Ivy.  We have little doubt that for third-party jars, a common repository that is integrated into the build system has tremendous advantage.

The struggle is around how to handle artifacts that are strictly internal.  We have many artifacts that use a handful of different build tools, including Maven, but essentially they are all part of one one product (one team responsible for all of it).  Unfortunately, we are not currently producing a single artifact per project, but we're headed in that direction.  Developers do and will check out all the projects.

We see two options:

1) Treat all artifacts even internal ones as any third-party jar.  Each jar gets built and published to the repository, and other artifact projects refer to the repository for all projects.

2) Each project refers to other "sibling" projects directly.  There is a "master project" that triggers the builds for all other projects with an appropriate dependency order.  In the IDE (eclipse), each projects refers to it's dependent project (source) directly. The build tools look into the sibling project referencing a .jar.

It's very clear that the open-source world is moving towards the repository model.  But it seems to us that their needs may be different.  Most such projects are very independent and we strongly suspect users are seldom making changes across projects.  There are frequent upgrades that are now easier for clients to track and be aware of.

However, it does add a burden in that you have to separately publish changes.  In our case, we just want to commit to source control (something we do 20-50 times a day).

I'm aware that Maven *might* solve all these problems, but the team is **NOT** going to convert everything to Maven.  Other than maven, what do you recommend (and why)?

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary to choose only one of your options.  I successfully use both in combination.  If a project consists of multiple modules, they are all built together, and *then* delivered to the repository.  However, the upload only happens for "official" or "release" builds.  The ongoing development builds are done at the developers' machines.  You don't have to use Maven for this.  Ivy would work or even a manual process.  The "artifact repository" could be one of the excellent [products](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Maven+Repository+Manager+Feature+Matrix) available or just a filesystem mount point.

*It's all about figuring out the appropriate component boundaries.*

When you say "developers do and will check out all projects", that's fine.  You never know when you might want to make a change; there's no harm in having a working copy ready.  But do you really want to make every developer to build every artifact locally, even if they do not need to change it?  Really, is every developer changing every single artifact?

Or maybe you just don't have a very big product, or a very big team.  There's nothing wrong with developing in a single project with many sub-projects (which may themselves have sub-modules).  Everybody works on everything together.  A single "build all" from the top does the job.  Simple, works, fast (enough).  So what would you use a shared repository for in this case?  Probably nothing.

Maybe you need to wait until your project/team is bigger before you see any benefit from splitting things up.

But I guarantee you this: you have some fundamental components, which are depended on (directly or indirectly) by many projects but do not themselves depend on any internal artifacts.  Ideally, these components wouldn't change very much in a typical development cycle.  My advice to you is twofold:

1. set up an internal repository since you already agree that you will benefit from doing so, if only for third-party jars.
2. *consider* separating the *most* fundamental project into a separate build, and delivering its artifact(s) to the repository, then having the rest of the system reference it **as if** it were a third-party artifact.

If a split like this works, you'll find that you're rebuilding that fundamental piece only when needed, and the build cycle for the rest of the project (for your developers) is faster by a corresponding amount: win-win.  Also, you'll be able to use a different delivery schedule (if desired) for the fundamental component(s), making the changes to it more deliberate and controlled (which is as it should be for such a component).  This helps facilitate growth.

Answer (score 0):

If a project produces multiple jar files (and many do) I would carefully consider (case by case) whether or not each jar will ever be reused by other projects.

If yes, that jar should go into the repository as a library, because it facilitates reuse by allowing you to specify it as a dependency.

If no, it would be a so-called "multi-project" in which the whole project is built of the parts. The individual jars probably do not need to be stored individually in the repo. Just the final completed artifact.

Gradle is definitely a candidate for you: It can use Ant tasks and call Ant scripts, understands Maven pom files, and handles multi-projects well. Maven can do much of this as well, and if you have lots of patience, Ant+Ivy can.